# HTML5 Saving Image from a Canvas in Javascript (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, canvas

Im trying to make a HTML5 signature capture in Javascript.

It works already but i got a problem running it on Android.

The function canvas.toDataURL(); does not work on Androids standard browser.

Does someone know an alternative for saving a Canvas to an image(png)? Or making it run on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Hans Schmucker's workaround/reimplementation:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1251575

Comment: Yes indeed. After spending the hole last day making this work, i finally got some results... So when i use this function on a small Canvas (e.g. 100x100px) then this works as intended. BUT when i use it on a big one (e.g. 1000x786px) then i never get results and the browser stops Reacting after a short time. I need to be honest that i don't understand the code completely of the function Hans Schmucker has written. So maybe it gets stuck in an infinite loop or something when used on a big canvas. Do you know whats wrong or what   i can do to fix this?

Comment: It doesn't get stuck in an infinite loop, the difference is that is has a lot more to process. For a 100x100 canvas it has 10.000 points each with red, green, blue, alpha ( times 4 ), so the data block is 40.000. When you have a 1000x786 canvas, the data block is considerably bigger, 786.000 points times 4.